# How to convert NaN value in CSV file to 0?

Tags: java

```
 while (scan.hasNext()){
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        scan.hasNextLine();
        line = line.trim();
        int countWhitespace = line.length() - line.replaceAll(" ", "").length(); 

        if (line.length() >0){
            int k = -1;
            int j = -1;

            k = -1;
            while (true){   
                k = line.indexOf(NaN, k+1);
                if (k<0) break;
                String result = NaN.replaceAll("NaN", value);
            }

        }
    }
```

- I have a CSV file and include of NaN value.
- I want to read this file and change NaN to 0.
- How can i solve it?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you reading or writing? Well, I guess it doesn't really matter: `if (Double.isNaN(value)) value = 0.0;`

Comment: Sorry for forget code, and I put my code already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`k = line.indexOf(NaN, k+1);` - this does not work because `line` is `String`.

Change to:

```
k = line.indexOf("NaN", k+1);
if (k<0)
    break;
String result = String.replace("NaN", value);
```

`value` should be of `String` type too.

If you convert each `String` to `double` somewhere later, you
could prefer converting `NaN` `double`s on this stage.

---

I like this elegant method to remove `NaN` **numbers**:

```
if (some_double!=some_double)
    some_double=0.0
```

because

> any != comparison involving NaN returns true, including x!=x when x is NaN.

Comment: @Anonymous Not at all! P.S.: You've chosen the most popular nick! ;)